# Xcode debug view hierarchy loads forever and won't start

Tags: xcode

The view hierarchy debugger won't work anymore on one of my projects. Or more precisely, it loads infinitely and never shows anything. Note that my app seems to be working fine, and that it works perfectly on other projects. I rebooted, cleaned everything etc.

What could possibly prevent it from loading ?

Comment: Which Xcode and macOS versions are you using?

Comment: Xcode 12, Catalina

Comment: Does it work if you hit a breakpoint on the main thread in your code and invoke it from there?

Comment: @wolfrevo I'm having the same problem but using a breakpoint didn't work, any other suggestion? I'm using the same versions as OP